# Android custom dialog imageviews

Tags: android, dialog, textview, imageview

I am trying to add a second image into my custom dialog but I am getting an error but no reason. Are you only allowed one image and textview per custom dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on custom dialogs if you are using your own layout.  please see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

or

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-custom-dialog.html

for a few examples.

or post your code and logcat so we can see the error (errors don't happen without a reason - and the error probably tells you the reason).